# Installing Windows Service - No mapping between account names and security ID's were done

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I have a windows service and setup project. When I right click on the setup project and click install it prompt me for

- Username
- Password
- Confirm Password

I have tried the following combinations

.\MyUserName
MyDomain\MyUserName

but it comes back with the following error

**No mapping between account names and security ID's were done**

**ServiceProcessInstaller**

```
namespace TestService
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {

        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = ServiceAccount.User;
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = @".\MyUserName"; //username;
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = "123456"; // password;

            // Add installers to collection. Order is not important.
        }

        private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void serviceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

To be honest, I'm not even sure why I am prompted for a username and password if I set it in the code...

Answer (score 46):

Please cross check whether you have done the following steps (**especially step 5**):

1. After creating the windows service project go to the service class's design view(just  double click the service1.cs class).
2. In the design view right click and select Add Installer. This will create an Installer class named ProjectInstaller.cs. With out ProjectInstaller.cs or any error in configuring ProjectInstaller.cs may result in non-showing of the service in service console.
3. Go to the design view of ProjectInstaller.cs you will find two installers there->

   a.**ServiceInstaller1**

   b.**ServiceProcessInstaller1**
4. Right click ServiceInstaller1 and go to the properties tab

   a.Edit the ServiceName with the name you want to 
   see your service in the service console.

   b.Change the **StartType** to **Automatic**.
5. **Right click ServiceProcessInstaller1 and go to the properties tab**

   a. Change the account to **LocalService**

Save and try it.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.  If I want to configure a more specific user I can always do that after I get the service installed.

Comment: 5 years later and still a valid answer

Comment: @IndieTechSolutions it's 11 years, but still a valid answer here too!

Answer (score 11):

Your DOMAIN\USERNAME format is correct for a domain, but if you're using a local username, use the computer name for the domain name. If your hostname is FOO and your username is BAR, you'd use FOO\BAR.

You're sure your user account is allowed to escalate, right? It's possible to forbid that via network and local security policy.

Try it with an admin account if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I found a remedy for this situation----however I am using
VM WARE cloned 2008 r2's.

Change the SID on the Server 2008 R2 in question using the following steps:

http://www.brajkovic.info/windows-server-2008/windows-server-2008-r2/how-to-change-sid-on-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2-using-sysprep/

This helped me remove the error.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the configuration code below in InitializeComponent method installer.

```
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but for me specifically, the issue was resolved by entering the username in username@domain.com format. E.g., if `foo` is the username and `bar.com` is the domain, then enter `foo@bar.com` as the username. No need to change any project files or change the credentials after installation.

Answer (score 0):

Right click ServiceProcessInstaller1 and go to the properties tab

```
Change the account to **LocalService**
```

This worked for me